# how to deal with Line Break <br/> when working with xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, contains

I am trying to find xpath for the links(Anchor tags `<a>`) from below HTML code.

**Note:** I don't want to use absolute xpath, so I am using xpath's `contains()` function

```
<div class="productList">
   <table class="product-listing-table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="product-desc">
              <a class="pt_sort">Product & Description</a>
           </th>
            <th>
               <a class="pc_sort">
                 Product
                 <br/>
                 Category
               </a>
            </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Below xpath gives me 'Product & Description', But in similar way if I am trying to find the next product with text as 'Product Category', it gives me error

```
.//th/a[contains(text(),'Product & Description')]
```

Above xpath Works

```
.//th/a[contains(text(),'Product Category')]
```

This one does not works.

Can somebody help?

Comment: It gives you what error? NB There are no links here, only anchors. A link would be given by an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below xpath

```
"//a[contains(text(),'Product') and contains(.,'Category')]"
```

Here **contains(.,'Category')** check for the inner text of any child tags of given tag